# Dump postgres table into a directory structure?

Tags: postgresql, export, postgresql-13

I have a table "templates" with about 150 records.  Each record has various attributes, but the one of greatest interest is the "template" column, which is a text field that contains an entire rather large ruby template file.

I would like to be able to more easily diff and compare these templates, view them in a text editor with syntax highlighting, etc.  I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/54535230/5419599 which does allow me to successfully dump out the "template" column into a separate file, one file per record.  However when looking at the files it would be very helpful to have immediate access to the other info about that template (i.e. the other original columns of the "templates" table in postgres).

It seems that for a table of this small size, it could be very handy to be able to dump the whole thing into a *directory structure*.  Each record would become a separate directory, named according to the "id" field of the record (which is the primary key), and have files in it named according to the column name, with contents according to the values in the table.

So in a directory called "6" (for record id 6) there would be a "template" file with the ruby template from `select template from templates where id = 6`, and also a "name" file containing the name of the record, etc.

This seems like a fairly obvious direct translation of a table structure into directories and files, which leads me to think possibly somebody has already written such a tool or capability?  It's almost like "how to convert an SQL table into a noSQL record" except I want to put it on disk as files, not as a JSON object somewhere.

<sub>(Side note, the real underlying problem, out of scope for this site, is that I'm looking at a new Foreman installation and an old Foreman installation and trying to compare the customized provisioning templates on the old, to the built-in templates on the new, and see what customizations we need to keep versus what built-in template logic needs to be updated to work with the new Foreman.)</sub>